# Rails get records after a certain ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app because records get created frequently I don't want to use a standard pagination mechanism because records wouldn't always be on the same page (records on page 2 today, might be on page 3 tomorrow). Instead what I want to do is request records after a certain ID.

So let's say I have 100 records in my posts table ranging from IDs 1-100, and I show 10 records at a time.

What I want to do is using `params[:after]` is request posts after that ID.

So if I have `params[:after] == 10` I want to get records `11-21` (though 21 may not exist, so it's really 10 records in the table `created_at` ordered `desc` from the ID onwards.

In my controller I have something like:

```
if params[:after].present?
  start_id = params[:after]
  end_id = start_id+10
  @posts = Post.where(:id => start_id..end_id).order('created_at desc').limit(10)
else
  @posts = Post.order('created_at desc').limit(10)
end
```

The problem I have is that the `end_id` will return the `start_id+10` but in the DB the next 10 records IDs might not be that, so I'd end up with incorrect IDs coming back.

So ideally I need to know what the ID of the 10th post from this one is. How can I do this?

Comment: you can not use ruby reserve keyword i.e.
`end=start+10`
here i think it will give you syntax error 
`end` is a ruby reserve keyword

Comment: @Rahul Updated.

Comment: @Cameron what about `Post.where("id >  ?", start_id).limit(10)`

Comment: @Cameron Post.where('id > ?', start_id).order('created_at').limit(10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case `params[:after]` is given I would do the following:

```
Post.where('table_name.id > ?', start).order('id desc').limit(10)
```

If you don't cheat on `created_at` column, the order on `created_at` and `id` columns should be the same, and ordering is much faster in `id` column (it has an index of numbers and that stuff)

Including the table name in the start condition is optional, but will help you avoid ambiguous SQL in case you want to join several tables.

Comment: Though I amended to check I had posts after that ID: `if Post.where('id > ?', start_id).empty?
  redirect_to posts_path and return
else
  @posts = Post.where('id > ?', start_id).order('created_at asc').limit(5)
end`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
Post.where('id > ?', start_id).order('created_at').limit(10)
```

Hope this will work for you